# HTML5 / CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, animation, css

my goal is to build a short HTML/CSS3/JavaScript animation that will be plugged into an iPad web app. What I'm essentially after is a canvas (image) that will have several regions the user can tap to zoom to and get additional info in a popup (overlay box) for each.

I can code HTML/CSS prety well but my JavaScript skills a a bit behind.

I was wondering if there is any sort of software/toolkit that I can use to achieve what I'm after. I did look into Sencha Animator (the interractivity I'm after seems to be missing), PhoneGap and jQTouch dont have the animation capabilities (except for few sliding/fading transitions).

Any suggestions?

Comment: did my answer, answer your question?

Comment: The final 1.0 release of Sencha Animator added the interactivity you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Indeed! Adobe released one in DW CS5. I've personally never tried it but here is the link to the announcement:
http://blogs.adobe.com/designandweb/2010/05/moving_the_web_forward.html